# Use jQuery/JS to split a single <ul> into four separate <ul>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single `<ul>` dynamically generated with anywhere between 8 and 25 `<li`>'s.

Example HTML:

```
<ul id="genList">
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
 <li>five</li>
 <li>six</li>
 <li>seven</li>
 <li>eight</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to split this single `<ul>` into four columns?

I've got this so far:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var size = 4,
      $ul  = $("ul"),
      $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
      loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size),
      i    = 0;

  $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

  for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
    $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + 4)).insertAfter($ul);
  }
});
```

Which just wraps it into columns 4 deep. I need to divide the `<ul>` into 4 first and pass the rounded value to the `var size`.

Edit: Needs to support IE8 and above and maintain vertical integrity of the list (column one goes: 1, 2 etc).

Comment: So the issue is that you're creating columns 4 deep, but instead you want to create rows 4 across?

Comment: I want to create 4 separate lists with equal quantities of the original ul.

Comment: @JayDee How about this: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gCKKY/) or may be this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCKKY/1/)

Comment: Why do you need javascript/jQuery here, with CSS only you can float them into 4 columns

Comment: What is creating the original list? It would be far more efficient to produce the correct result than to massage the result into another.

Comment: @MichaelB. How would I float a dynamic amount length of a list into four columns using only CSS?

Comment: @BernhardHofmann it's generated by the server which I have no access to, the only way to massage the data is to do it client side.

Comment: Using nth-child odd and evens then odd and evens again to divide it into 4 coulumns could work perhaps... Hadn't tried implementing that approach before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified the posted Javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var rows = 4,
      $ul  = $("ul"),
      $lis = $ul.children(),
      size = Math.ceil($lis.length / rows), 
      $lis = $lis.filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
      loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size),
      i    = 0;

  $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

  for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
      $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + size)).insertAfter($ul);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Four columns with CSS only would be something like this

```
#genList li{
      width:22%;
      float:left;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
```

You could also use fixed widths..

Comment: Thanks for this, but this floats the list elements left to right, they need to be vertical (traditional <li> style) split into 4 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Y3SDQ/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#genList li").replaceWith(function() {
          return $("<p/>").append($(this).html());
    });
    $("#genList").replaceWith($("<div/>",{"class":"cols", "id":"genlist"}).html($("#genList").html()));
});
```

using this CSS

```
.cols { column-count:4;
-moz-column-count:4; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:4; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.cols p { margin-top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this to recursive too, if that is what you want:

```
separate($('#genList'), 4);

function separate($ul, size) {

    var $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
        loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size);            
    $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

    for (var i = 0; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
        $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + size)).insertAfter($ul);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/bg3Fd/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through CSS, though you will have to set widths or margins for the li elements:

```
#genList li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#genList li:nth-of-type(5),
#genList li:nth-of-type(9),
#genList li:nth-of-type(13),
#genList li:nth-of-type(17),
#genList li:nth-of-type(21),
#genList li:nth-of-type(25) {
    clear:both;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5wJ3/1/)**